# Appenders in the Log4j2 xml configuration

Tags: java, log4j2

I have two RollingFile Appenders in the below XML config file. Whenever I run the application, I can only see the data in the `test1.log` file (appender reference details (`name="dataCapture"`)), and I'm not able to see any data inside `test2.log` file. I'm completely new log4j2.

Is it always required to pass appenders reference name to `Loggers` block then only logs will be printed on the file?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
       
 
        <RollingFile name="dataCapture" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/test1.log" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/test1.%i.log.gz"">
            <PatternLayout>
              <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30" />
        </RollingFile>


        <RollingFile name="DATACAPTURE" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/test2.log" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/test2.%i.log.gz"">
            <PatternLayout>
              <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
          <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30" />
        </RollingFile>
 
        
    </Appenders>
 
    <Loggers>
 
        <logger name="com.rest.db.fetch" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="dataCapture" />
        </logger>
 

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="dataCapture"  />
        </Root>
 
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You don't see anything in `test2.log` because you didn't attach the `DATACAPTURE` appender to any logger. Log message propagate in two directions: the appenders directly attached to the logger (logger config to be precise) and to the parent logger and its appenders (unless `additivity="false"`).

Comment: The XML you shared is not valid. Remove the redundant double quote here  filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/test1.%i.log.gz"" and try again